# Module positioning layout

Tags: content, layout, positions, module-style, helix3

I'm using the following theme based on helix3 framework and I'm encountering some issues on the positioning of the main content.

I have a row with 2 columns, the one the side is fine because it's a normal column and I can stack modules inside of it, the main content column instead gives me issues because the position is called "component" in the template layout, and I cannot add additionals modules to it (apart from the main content module that you choose when making the menu entry).

I could add another row with the same column layout but it wouldn't stack with the previous column if the heights of the 2 previous columns are not equal.

This is the template
[image]

I need to add content under "column 1".

This is the layout
[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your imgae, the next position on bottom for your "content" was in "Lower Body".

Did you try add your content in "Lower Body Position"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add new module positions directly from the Template administrator panel:

> Our main aim was to move possibly a large number of parameters to
>   administrative panel which normally were changed in template code
>   directly. Thanks to this, beginner users, can easily add new module
>   positions and change many settings in administrator panel from
>   template option level.
>   (https://www.joomshaper.com/blog/helix-v3-template-framework-feature-suggestions)